# On integration limits of exponential integral

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-distribution

My questions seems pretty simple but I am really confuses with following statement
Considering **w,x,y and z as exponential independent random variables** with ZERO mean. What will be probability of following

**Pr(w*x< Ay*z+B)**

**where A and B are constants**.
I tried with following integration limits but it is not giving the correct results.

$1- \displaystyle\left(\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}  e^{\dfrac{-yzA}{w}} e^{-y}e^{-z}e^{-w} \,dy\,dz\,dw\right) \left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\dfrac{B}{w}-w} \,dw\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd.. you mention "trying integration limits" but you don't have any non-trivial limits on your integrals.

This is in the form $P(Y < aX + b)$ where $Y$ and $X$ are independent random variables with the distribution of the product of two standard exponentials (I assume that the four exponentials are independent). If $f$ is the PDF for the product of two exponentials, then you have $$ P(Y< aX+b) = \int_0^\infty dx\int_0^{\max(ax+b,0)}dy f(x)f(y)$$ where I took care of the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are both positive. This is just integrating the joint PDF $f(x)f(y)$ over the region where $y < ax + b.$

Then you need to find $f$, the PDF for the product of two independent exponentials.

Comment: can u tell me how can i find joint pdf  of two exponential random variables when the limit is not known :/

Comment: @hakkunamattata No idea what you're asking. What limit?